# Forward freeradius attributes to an external api using rlm_rest

Tags: freeradius, radius

I am proxying the radius request to an external radius server for a specific realm.once the external radius replies back with an access accept packet and other attributes,I want to forward the attributes to an External api for some processing.

How can I achieve this?
I have configured my freeradius rest file with the appropriate endpoint and the default file under sites-enabled to forward the request to rest.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do is package the attributes in a JSON post to the external API via the rlm_rest post_proxy.
Configure your rest module as needed and grab the attributes you want to send over the wire.

```
post-proxy {
    uri = "${..connect_uri}/at"
    method = 'post'
    body = 'json'
    data = '{"User-Name":"%{User-Name}","User-Password":"%{User-Password}","NAS-IP-Address":"%{NAS-IP-Address}","NAS-Port":"%{NAS-Port}","Event-Timestamp":"%{Event-Timestamp}"}'

}
```